# Occasional javascript type and runtime errors invoked by Webkit sandbox (path VMxxx:x)

Tags: jquery, requirejs, webkit, sandbox, typeerror

I'm developing webapp and to load various js libraries I use require.js.
Sometimes, when I'm loading some *.html views into DOM using jQuery's load(),  require.js itself isn't loaded properly and I get `Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function` (tested on Opera and Chrome) but with strange path of **VM1934:5** (not always same numbers of course), instead of path to script's line which tried to load contents but failed, i.e. **script.js:123**.

This is how the strack trace looked like this time:

```
Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function       VM452:5
(anonymous function) @ VM452:5
(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
m.extend.globalEval @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
m.fn.extend.domManip @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
m.fn.extend.append @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
m.access @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
m.fn.extend.html @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
j @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
x @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5b @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
```

I guess that this path with VM indicates that someting went wrong during particular script runtime in browser's sandbox, but I'm not sure.

If anybody could explain me, why this happened or point me to a proper docs describing such webkit's behaviour of using VMxxx:x as path for indicating code conflicts, it would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: The error itself is saying everything. when your script uses `require` may be it is not loaded there and the script tries to use it.

Comment: @Jai ok, but why the error source path points to line of code in sandbox (VM452:5) instead straight to unsandboxed script which is responsible for error?
Why this VMxxx path is displayed here?

Comment: may be as requirejs is amd based but i am not sure.

Comment: may be this could help: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html